# How can I add JSF project facet to Google App Engine project

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jsf-2

I can't seem to add the JSF project facet to my GAE project in Eclipse.

It states that it requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5+ but it is not even an option with this project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing Jboss Tools first from Eclipse Marketplace